# How return foregin key existence information to select result?

Tags: mysql, select, exists

I have a query:

```
    SELECT `Name`, `ID_dir`, 999 as `children` 
    FROM `dir` dir WHERE dir.`fid_parent` IS NULL 
    AND (
      EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   `file` f
         WHERE  dir.ID_dir = f.fid_parent
         )
       OR (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   `dir` d2
         WHERE  dir.ID_dir = d2.fid_parent
       )
    )
```

Where I check if the directory has any foreign key.
How can I move that information in place of 999 in "Select ... 999 as `children`"?
I want to return (0 or 1) xor Boolean in that place as `children`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `EXISTS` subquery in the `SELECT` list.

```
SELECT Name, ID_Dir, (
      EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   `file` f
         WHERE  dir.ID_dir = f.fid_parent
         )
       OR (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   `dir` d2
         WHERE  dir.ID_dir = d2.fid_parent
       )
    ) AS children
FROM dir WHERE fid_parent IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like i tried this before but with some mistakes, so it didn't work.